# convert/use rosbag1 with ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just got several datasets in the form of ROS1 rosbags.

I would like to use them within ROS2 (humble), either by converting them to ROS2 bags, or by replaying them in ROS2, whatever is easier. Or even extract the data to text files + images.

I had the same situation before, while still using Ubuntu 20.04, and solved it playing the bags in ROS1, then using ros1_bridge to convert them to ROS2.

On Ubuntu 22.04 however, ROS1 (Noetic) is not supported as far as I understand, so I can't run the rosbag play in ROS1.

So how can I possibly get the data out of a ROS1 bag on ubuntu 22.04? Do you know any conversion tool not depending on ROS1?

Thanks a lot in advance
Felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403382/convert/use-rosbag1-with-ros2-on-ubuntu-22.04/) by [felixn](https://answers.ros.org/users/104669/felixn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The developers behind Ternaris released conversion tools some time ago.

See [Rosbags - the pure python library for everything rosbag](https://discourse.ros.org/t/rosbags-the-pure-python-library-for-everything-rosbag/20944) for the announcement on ROS Discourse.

See [ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags](https://ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags/index.html) for the documentation.

Specifically: [convert](https://ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags/topics/convert.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixn](https://answers.ros.org/users/104669/felixn/) on 2022-07-06**:
Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly (and even faster than real time).

Just one note for those trying to do the same : the rosbags-convert command has to be used directy in terminal, and not from a python script as one might think from the python example just above in the documentation

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-07-06**:\

> Just one note for those trying to do the same : the rosbags-convert command has to be used directy in terminal, and not from a python script as one might think from the python example just above in the documentation

wasn't that clear from the [convert](https://ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags/topics/convert.html) page? It states:

> The `rosbags.convert` package includes a CLI tool to convert legacy rosbag1 files to rosbag2 and vice versa.

"CLI tool" -> "command line interface tool".

**Comment by [felixn](https://answers.ros.org/users/104669/felixn/) on 2022-07-06**:
true : I probably foccussed too much on the "getting started" page : on the convert page, it is clear indeed